# Does React automatically send cookies set by the server on every subsequent request?

Tags: reactjs, cookies

Trying to understand cookies better.

I assume that if a React app calls an endpoint which sets cookies, those cookies are sent back to the server on every subsequent request, automatically. That is, React doesn't have to specifically handle the "incoming" cookie in any way; and it includes it in all future requests.

Is that true? Does the browser handle all the details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the usual cookie behaviour.

- Server sends cookie to client.
- Client, on subsequent request, attaches the cookie for the particular server domain

There is no need to do any special handling in order to send the cookie to the server.

Read [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)